# Random UITable Delegate crash when selecting filled table

Tags: ios, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I am creating a simple app to select video urls out of a UITable. I have hooked my data source and delegate to a UIViewController subclass and the table is filled correctly. Also, it recognizes selections and prints to the log.

My issue is that it gets a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" and crashes when I select a cell. I am looking through the code and the error propagates to this method:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"SelectionIdentifier";

  //Errors start happening this next line
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  if(cell ==  nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }
  //NSString* str = [[videos objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] lastPathComponent];
  NSString* test = @"test";
  [[cell textLabel] setText:test];
  return cell;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView*)myTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//  NSLog(@"Selected!");
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return [videos count];
}
```

I'm not sure why this error is getting thrown in this method. Any fixes? I double checked to make sure the videos array wasn't nill.

I did another app that used this same method and it doesn't cause these errors.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you go ahead and show the code for some of the other table functions? Also, make sure that the delegates are setup appropriately.

Comment: Sure. I have updated it to have these methods. These are the only methods I have implemented for the delegate and data source. I also double checked the connections on the storyboard.

Comment: I have it declared as IBOutlet UITableView* tableView;

Comment: I then have it hooked up through "interface builder" in Xcode 4's storyboards

Comment: I can email you the code if you want. It's just a small start of an app. Nothing big, crazy, or complicated at all.

Comment: I redid all the UITableView stuff and moved the Array initialization from the initWithNib function to the viewDidLoad method and now it works. :-) Thanks guys for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of testing **if(cell == nil)** try using **if(!cell)**. Honestly I'm not sure this is the issue, but after reviewing this I do not think that the error is not actually inside this method (it may somehow be related which is why it brings you here).

If this is only after you select a cell though, why is this method being called?

Comment: I originally had if(!cell), but changing it back still made the error happen. I'm not sure why this method is getting called to be honest. The didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is blank and does nothing at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should also call this method.Because this is preliminary delegate method

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}
```

After seeing your tableView i am not finding any problem at all.Try that may be it will be solve.